# css ID with or without HTML element?

Tags: html, css

In a css file, is it better to use css ID's with or without the HTML element?

For example, with HTML element:

```
div#header {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Without HTML element:

```
#header {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

I understand that both examples will do the same thing, but I'm wondering if either example will affect SEO or loading times. I'm leaning towards using the example *without* the HTML element as this will result in a smaller CSS file, but I'm wondering if anyone else has thoughts/opinions/experience on this.

Comment: Without... it uses less characters, which keeps the size of your CSS file to a minimum.

Comment: The id is  an absolute identifier and then the html elemet is unuseful

Comment: Depends on whether the form of the element is essential to its rule-application. 99 times out of 100, this would be "no; go without". A counter-example might be if you want to set a particular font on an ID, but *only* if it's part of an input, as opposed to a div or span. (This is assuming the same CSS file is applied to multiple pages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div#header {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Will only be applied if the element holding the id is a div.

```
#header {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Will work regardless of the element.

Since you should only use an id once you'd usually go for the second approach: it saves characters and therefore a tiny bit of loading time - not really noticable though.

If you are having several pages using the css but the #header element can be different using div#header can be a way to decide which style to apply to which page. If this is the case however, you probably want to use a class here.